# My Oracle Data is not inserting no matter what I do

Tags: php, database, oracle

I am working on core php and I have to insert data into oracle system. The data will come from API from a flutter app. here is my query

```
 $response = oci_parse($c,"INSERT INTO  conf.confidential(WPP_MASTER_ID,CODE,TYPE_ID,WIP_ENTITY_ID,WIP_ENTITY_NAME,WPP_DATE_DATE,DURATION_HRS_F,DURATION_HRS_T,WPP_ISSUED_TO,WPP_ISSUED_TO_NAME,WPP_ISSUED_TO_DEPT_NAME,WORK_ORDER_DESCRIPTION,WORK_ORDER_CHANGE_DESC,ASSET_DESCRIPTION,ASSET_DEPARTMENT,ASSET_ACTIVITY,STATUS,PARA1,ISOLATED_BY_ID,ISOLATED_BY,PARA2,PARA3,PARA4,PARA5,PARA6,PARA7,PARA8,PARA9,PARA10,INVIGILATOR_BY_ID,INVIGILATOR_BY,INVIGILATOR_REMARKS,ANY_OTHER_PRECAUTION,PRORECTIVE_EQPT_1,PRORECTIVE_EQPT_2,PRORECTIVE_EQPT_3,PRORECTIVE_EQPT_4,PRORECTIVE_EQPT_5,PRORECTIVE_EQPT_6,PRORECTIVE_EQPT_7,PRORECTIVE_EQPT_8,PRORECTIVE_EQPT_9,PRORECTIVE_EQPT_10,PRORECTIVE_EQPT_NONE,EXTENSION_FLAG,WPP_RECEIPT_TO,WPP_RECEIPT_TO_NAME,WPP_RECEIPT_TO_DEP_NAME,CREATED,CREATED_BY,UPDATED,UPDATED_BY,SAFTEY_ANALYSIS,WF_LEVEL,OWNING_DEPARTMENT,OWNING_DEPARTMENT_CODE,DURATION_HRS,ASSET_NUMBER,ASSET_AREA,RECEIVED_BY,EXTEND_BY,EXTENDED_RECEIVED_BY,EXTEND_DATE,EXTEND_HOURS,RECEIVED_DATE,COMPLETED_BY,COMPLETED_DATE,COMPLETED_RECEIVED_BY,COMPLETION_REMARKS,EXTENSION_REMARKS,LEL_LEVEL,CODE_NEW,CODE_OLD) 
                    VALUES ('3287','1PP03PMC22031082','Cold','null','11588174','1-MAY-22','1-MAY-22','1-MAY-22','null','Test Test Test','null','This Work Permit is only used for test purpose','null','GLYCOL CIRCULATION PUMP','null','null','Submitted','N','null','null','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','N','null','null','Muhammad Nauman Ali','null','Be careful, avoid any damage','Y','Y','N','N','N','Y','N','N','null','null','N','null','null','null','null','28-MAR-22','Majid Iftikhar ','28-MAR-22','majid.iftikhar@ifl.net','null','2','658','PP1 POLY3M','4','110305-1868-P05-001','1103-01-POLYMER +0.0M','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','null','1PP03PMC22031082','null')");
```

This is the error I am receiving at the moment,

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  oci_execute(): ORA-01722: invalid number in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\workpermit\workpermit_createWorkPermit.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
{"status":"false","data":"No data Found"}
```

I don't know what am I  doing wrong, even If I remove the first two values, and columns I still get the error. Has anyone ever faced such issue?

Comment: Double-check your database schema, and try to make sure you're not trying to insert a string with letters into a number field. Also if you're trying to insert `'1-MAY-22'` into a date field, I don't think that's a correct format for Oracle.

Comment: There's a difference between `'null'` you use (enclosed into single quotes, so it is a string) and `null` as absence of a value. I presume you should use the latter, not the former but - we can't know for sure unless you post table description. Also, see what @aynber said about date values. Use date literal: `date 2022-05-01'`

Comment: PLEASE share your table definitinon, that is, the CREATE TABLE statement for CONF.CONFIDENTIAL.

Comment: You can [edit] the question to update it with the schema information. P.S. The PHP aspect of this appears to be irrelevant, since the query text is hard-coded. You'd have the same issue running it directly in an Oracle environment.

Comment: If you're new to PHP and Oracle, read the [OCI8 manual](https://www.php.net/manual/book.oci8.php) and chapter 10 onwards in [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/underground-php-oracle-manual.html)

Comment: @aynber Actually, we are working for a company that is very paranoid about their database. We use team viewer to develop the APIs. That's why I don't have much information regarding their database schema. Also the date, they told us to put it like this. Thank you very much for telling me that this is not a correct format. I will notify.

Comment: @Littlefoot Thank you very much, I have changed the 'null' to null, meanwhile I have written a email to the company's team to please share the schema and table definition so we can understand, I will share it here if they share, to understand better what they want.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, yes I have written an email to the company's database team to share the definition with us.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thank you so much for sharing this. Yes I started my PHP journey 5 months ago, Thank you so much this helps me to understand many things. I will post information here, once I receive it.